# Html Form Outlook-2010

Tags: html, outlook-2010

In a project I am sending an email to a user. In this email there will be an html form in which user can fill and make an http post request. I have tried sending a normal html page with links and it seem well on outlook-2010 like it do on browsers. However when i embed html form code inside email its not generating like its generating in a browser view. Thus, can we embed an html form in an email and see it as expected in outlook 2010.

Answer (score 2):

No.

HTML parsers/renderers in email clients vary from "Actual browsers" to "Actual browsers which only get the HTML after some vicious preprocessing" to "Jokes".

Forms are a no-no in emails. Include a URL to a form on a page on the WWW that the user can open in a browser instead.